# Rspec, can't call a method in my class for a ruby gem, error: ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `pull' for Status::Page:Module

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to call methods in my main class in rspec tests for a gem?

I have seen other questions like this one but none had an answer that worked with me, so I am asking this question.

I tried writing rspec tests for a gem that I am making (I am not using Rails), but I can't call the methods that are in my main file:

```
require "status/page/version"
require 'thor'
require "nokogiri"
require 'open-uri'
require 'date'

module Status
  module Page
    class CLI < Thor
      desc "pull", "query website status"
      def pull
      .....
```

That is how I am calling in the page_specs.rb file:

```
RSpec.describe Status::Page do
  it "has a version number" do
    expect(Status::Page::VERSION).not_to be nil
  end

  it "does something useful" do
    expect(true).to eq(true)
  end

  it "it should output to a file on pull" do
    msg = Status::Page.pull
    expect(msg).not_to be nil
  end

end
```

Can someone please advise how I should call the methods in Rspec in my case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Status::Page::CLI.new.pull`

`pull` is an instance method on the class `Status::Page::CLI`, and since it's an instance method you need to instantiate the class with `.new`.

Since the class inherits from Thor, the call to `.new` does go through [Thor::Base.initialize](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor%2FBase:initialize). But from the docs, it looks like default values are set for all the arguments, so just calling `.new` without args should suffice.

Comment: I wanna thank you very much, I have been trying to solve this for hours!
Also thanks for the great explanation :)